# Gatsby+netlif+contentful bridge

Tags: contentful, gatsby, netlify

I am trying to configure `contentful` webhook for auto deploy in `netlify`.
I am geting 404 during content changes.

Comment: Although @fool has supplied you with a pretty viable answer covering what he sees in customer support, this is not a complete question. You should include examples of the setup and examples of what you have tried. This is way too general.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I work for Netlify.

This setup works well for many customers.  I assume you have setup a separate build hook in the Build & Deploy settings page and are using it?  You cannot use our automatic webhooks that trigger builds from GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket to trigger builds from other external systems like Contentful.

There is no authentication required and a 404 suggests to me a mistyped webhook address as we'll only return 404's when you try to visit something that doesn't exist.

Do make sure that:

- your site is setup to build using our continuous deployment system.  You can't trigger a site that we can't fetch via git, and only sites fetched via git can be built via our CD.
- you use https
- you POST (I assume this is the default for Contentful's outgoing hooks but if you can choose - POST is what you want)
- your webhook host is api.netlify.com
- and in general you use the exact hook address you get from our UI.

If that doesn't show an obvious typo, this is probably something you'll need to contact our Tech Support about, including information like your webhook address and the site you are attempting to trigger a build from.